# scroll event after append item Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to call scroll event after append item but it is not working. what I do wrong?
Please help me Thank you.

you can check the code here
https://jsfiddle.net/4uk92cxe/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myDiv2').append(
"<table class='scroll-item'><tr><td> YYYYYYYYYYYYYY</td></tr></table>"
  );

  $('.scroll-item').on('scroll', function () {
     console.log('scrolling');
  });

  $(document).on('scroll', "table[class='scroll-item']", function () {
     console.log('scrolling');
  });

  $('.scroll-item').scroll(function () {
     console.log('scrolling');
  });

  $(document).on('scroll', '.scroll-item', function () {
     console.log('scrolling');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width:100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="scroll-item">
<tr>
  <td> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
</tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="myDiv2" class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the class scroll-item  in the table. Rmove it from table, and put it in the div content `.wrapper` that is holding the scrollbar.
**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myDiv2").addClass("scroll-item");

    $('#myDiv2').append(
        "<table ><tr><td> YYYYYYYYYYYYYY</td></tr></table>"
    );

    $('.scroll-item').on('scroll', function () {
        console.log('scrolling');
    });

});
```

```css
    .wrapper {
        width: 100px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    table {
        width: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="scroll-item wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="myDiv2" class="wrapper"></div>
```

Just add the class in the div: `$("#myDiv2").addClass("scroll-item");` and also, replace this class here `<div class="scroll-item wrapper">`.

You can also remove this: `$("#myDiv2").addClass("scroll-item");` and add the class directly in the HTML to avoid more work with Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question **what I do wrong?** is, you are calling on scroll on `.scroll-item` but the scroller is in the `.wrapper`.

use this instead,

```
$('.wrapper').on('scroll', function(){
  console.log('scrolling');
});
```